# How to sort the coordinate list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting, python-2.x

Suppose I have a coordinate list as the following:

```
list_ = [{'x':1,'y':2},{'x':1,'y':1},{'x':3,'y':3}]
```

I want to first sort `x` key, and then sort `y` key. So I expect:

```
list_ = [{'x':1,'y':1},{'x':1,'y':2},{'x':3:'y':3}]
```

How do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `key` parameter of `sort`/`sorted`.  You pass a function that returns the key to sort upon.  `operator.itemgetter` is an efficient way to generate the function:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> list_ = [{'x':1,'y':2},{'x':1,'y':1},{'x':3,'y':3}]
>>> sorted(list_,key=itemgetter('x','y'))
[{'x': 1, 'y': 1}, {'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 3, 'y': 3}]
```